# Is carrying permitted on Rosh Hashana without an eruv?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, eruv-chatzerot

I think I read somewhere recently that Rosh Hashanah is different than other Yom Tovs in that one may carry for certain mitzvah needs.

For example: A shofar or tallis or a siddur may be carried if I'm not mistaken.

But does mean it is permitted to carry from one domain to another without an eruv? And is that what they mean by allowed to carry since I thought an eruv always enables one to carry things within the eruv.

What makes Rosh Hashanah different or am I wrong about this...Do any other Yom Tov's allow this?

Comment: On all Yamim Tovim (except Yom Kippur) you can carry outside an Eruv for a purpose.

Comment: An eruv does not mean one can carry anything he wants. http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/700456/jewish/What-Is-an-Eruv.htm

Answer (score -2):

In summary, carrying from one domain to another is permitted on Yom Tov even if the carrying is not food related, providing that the item is not *muktzah*. You do not require an eruv.

This concept is called "mitoch", i.e. since the Torah permitted carrying for food it permitted carrying for non-food. See [this article](http://etzion.org.il/vbm/english/archive/moadim71/23-71moed.htm) for details on the Talmud discussion.

Comment: –1 because the answer doesn't include the oft-relevant limitation that the carrying be _l'tzorech hayom_.